# Permissions on SQL Server Sequences

Tags: sql-server-2016, permissions, sequence

The AD Group to which I belong has `db_owner permissions` on database LandingZone. The application I am debugging, that is running under my ID, is doing a `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR ThisSchema.ThatSequence.` I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 6
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'ThatSequence', database 'LandingZone', schema 'ThisSchema'.
```

I think I'm running into a `Least Privilege` issue but the production DBAs disagree.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

db_owner is supposed to have all permissions within given db, so you should be able to update that sequence without any problem - if your app really runs under your UserID

1) Check the connection string that app is using

If connection string does not contain `Integrated Security = True` or `Trusted Connection = True`, then you have to add those to connection string

2) if app is running from within some web server (IIS Web server etc.), and its included into some Application Pool, you need to make sure this Application Pool runs under security context of your Windows User...

3) to verify that your application is really connecting under your Windows credentials to SQL Server, while the app is connected to DB, check out following DMVs at SQL Server:

> select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
>   select * from sys.dm_exec_connections

(those can be linked by session_id, find session/connection of your application and make sure it runs under your Windows credentials (login_name "YourDomain\YourUserName")

4) if App is running and connecting to DB using your Windows creds, and you still have this permission issue, then you have to make sure your Windows user if really is in AD Group, and AD Group is really added to db_owner role at given database...

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue:
Are you sure the application is using your login? The application may be using a different login than yours.  Check the CONFIG file to see what login is being used when the application is running.  If it's different, then that login is the one that needs right perms.